# Apache NiFi extract only File-name from GetFile

Tags: apache-nifi

Below is a simple NiFi flow which monitors a folder for file and copies to a different folder. It works fine, but I'm looking for a processor which extracts only the filename and writes the name of the file in a text-file

I tried ExtractText processor but could not figure how to configure it to read only filename. Any advise is highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your use case correctly, you should be able to use ListFile -> ReplaceText -> UpdateAttribute -> PutFile.

ListFile will generate a flow file for each file it finds in the directory, but the flow file will not have any content, it will just put the filename in an attribute. Then you can use ReplaceText to replace the entire text (i.e. flow file contents) with `${filename}`. UpdateAttribute would be used to change the `filename` attribute to whatever you want the destination text file to be called, for use in PutFile.

Comment: Got it working. But the ListFile is not running continuously, if I start and stop the  workflow then it recognizes and process it .Is there anything I'm missing ?

Comment: ListFile run continuously based on the any updates happened in the files in metioned directory. if no changes written in the files in that directory then it won't pick up those existing files.